# Get images between start_month int and end_month int over new year

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple set up in the database such as per below:

```
|--------------|------------------|--------------|------------|
|    Image     |   Start Month    |  End Month   |   Active   |
|--------------|------------------|--------------|------------|
|  Image1.jpg  |       10         |       3      |      1     | - Show October this year to March next year, every year.
|  Image2.jpg  |        3         |      10      |      1     | - Show March to October, every year.
|  Image3.jpg  |        7         |       5      |      1     | - Show July this year to May next year; every year.
|  Image4.jpg  |        0         |     NULL     |            | - Show this image year round.
|--------------|------------------|--------------|------------|
```

The idea is to show images based on the month.  Every year it's the same so a year is not required.
Now the logic of how I am doing this is messing with my mind.

This month it's November (11). `$month = 11;`

The query I currently have is

```
 WHERE `start_month` <= $month AND `end_month` >= $month OR `start_month`= 0 ORDER BY RAND()
```

but that unfortunately only works mid year and doesn't compensate for the images that wrap around into the new year.

What logic do I need to select the images based on the current month `$month` between the `start_month` and `end_month` making it work for those images that cycle through the new year change.

Images with a `0` start month are to be displayed year round.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php and how to prevent from **sql injection**

Comment: Use parentheses to group the conditions in the `WHERE` clause. You can also use `$month BETWEEN start_month AND end_month`

Comment: @nbk I do use prepared statements when user variable data is entered into the database.  Since all variable data here is generated via the script `$month = date("m");` there is no risk of SQL injection.

Comment: use for all variables prepared statements. to your problem, moth allone are bad comapsison as you can't detect  10,1,12,1,2,3,4. so must take teh month otpo condsideration. and programm it . Use dates that makes it much easier